# Simple + Simple clauses when one event interrupts another

Tags: tense, conditional-constructions, progressive-aspect

> If he **had been standing** near the house when the wall collapsed, it would have killed him.
>
> If he **had stood** near the house when the wall collapsed, it would have killed him.

Does the second sentence sound jarring, or it is fully legitimate? Do I alway have to put one clause in the *continious* aspect when one event *interrupts* another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The past perfect of *to stand* is ***had stood*** rather than *had stand*, so editing your second sentence slightly to account for that we get:

> If he **had stood** near the house when the wall collapsed, it would have killed him.

And as you suspected, this does sound a little jarring. Past perfect [*had verbed*] should be used to describe actions which were already complete when another action in the past occurred. [*If he **had moved** closer to the building before it collapsed, he would have been killed.*] In this example the moving was a completed action before the wall fell.

Thus the correct usage would be the first example you listed, in the past perfect continuous.

> If he **had been standing** near the house when the wall collapsed, it would have killed him.

It is, however, not uncommon to hear the past continuous used in conditionals even when referring to a past condition. This is somewhat less common with the simple past, but again not unheard of.

Comment: Your last example shatters everything what I know about the third conditional. If during a past event I was not doing something, than after that I could never say "If I **was doing** it", it is always "If I **had been doing** it." That's the third conditional.

Comment: You're absolutely correct. Sorry about that! I did some digging and refreshed my memory on the way past perfect/past perfect continuous works differently in conditionals than in regular use, but I found a very high number of speakers using the simple past/past continuous to refer to a past conditional while I was searching. I removed my assertion that past continuous was the correct choice (since it isn't), but left in the mention that it's still used anyway (since it is). Regardless, the answer to your actual question stands as it was. Use the continuous.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate a bit on some parts of Emmabee's answer: the reason that your second example sounds a bit off rather than entirely incorrect is because the verb "stand" can imply either a state of being or an action, and in this case the default sense is a state of being.  For example, this sounds fine:

> If he had stood when the tornado passed over the ditch in which he was lying, it would have killed him.

In this case it's clear that *stand* implies a change of position.  We often clarify this meaning by adding "up": "If he had stood up" and so on.